# Twitter Bootstrap - fixed background (no scroll) when modal hide is in (like Pinterest zoom)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, background, modal-dialog

using Twitter Bootstrap:

when Modal is in and the background of page is under opacity, the background is scrollable but I need its fixed or static instead (no scrollable) like Pinterest when the zoom is in.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you please post the code or create a jsfiddle with wat you are working on or have tried , will be easier for us to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question here:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/407

Comment: What was the answer? There are plenty of answers there.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved in Bootstrap 3.0 modal.